# Regular expression in scrapy to get parameter of onclick function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Using scrapy, i want to fetch parameter of onclink function only, i am using response.css() to extract links.

If i am using regular expression for getting parameter only, got an error (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 're')

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover Tax" >
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Sr No.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Registration No</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Sectors</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
<tr>

    <td>1</td><td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='show_info("173543");'> ABCD</a></td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>Data Not Found</td>
                  </tr></tbody></table>
```

I am using Scrapy for Scrap onclick parameter

```
link_first = response.css(".table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.Tax>tbody>tr>td>a").xpath("./@onclick").extract().re("show_info\((.+?)\)", text)
```

Required O/P : 173543

Comment: `.extract()[0].re("show_info\((.+?)\)"`?

Comment: Thanks @Andersson By removing `.extract()` and `text` got my response

Answer (score 2):

`extract()` extracts the textual data as a list of strings .
To match selectors with regular expression, you need to use [`re()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) on selector itself.

```
html = """<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover Tax" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sr No.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Registration No</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Sectors</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<tr>

    <td>1</td><td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='show_info("173543");'> ABCD</a></td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>Data Not Found</td>
                </tr></tbody></table>"""

from scrapy.selector import Selector 
response= Selector(text=html)
links = response.css(".table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.Tax>tbody>tr>td>a").xpath("./@onclick").re("show_info\((.+?)\)")

print links
```

returns :

```
[u'"173543"']
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: or alternatively as Gangabass pointed out you can use `re_first` as a shortcut for getting only the first member.

Answer (score 0):

I use XPath `contains` to get correct `onclick` content and parse it using `re_first()`

```
link_id = response.xpath('//td/a[contains(@onclick, "show_info")]/@onclick').re_first( r'"([^"]+)"')
```

Comment: Please include some explanation with your answer.